# Algebraic Induction

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Given that $h=(5^2)^n-1$, how do I go about proving that $h$ is divisible by $24$ for all positive integers $n$, using induction, assuming $h/24$ is whole?

Here is my current method:

Assume that $P(n)=25^n-1=24m$, given that $m∈N$(positive integers)

$P(n+1)=25^{n+1}-1$

$P(n+1)=25^n25-1$

$P(n+1)=25(24m+1)-1$

$P(n+1)=25(24m)+24$

$P(n+1)=24(25m+1)$

Thus, given that $m∈N$, $25m+1$ must be a whole number, and thus for any $P(n)$, there must be a $P(n+1)$ divisible by 24.  My question is whether or not this is a valid inductive proof?

Comment: A typo: $h = (5^2)^n -1$, according to what you have written below.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake$$P(n+1) = 25(24m \color{red}+1) -1$$

If you have reach $25(24m)-26$, it is easy to see that the first part is divisible by $24$, but what about $26$? You have to justify it (though you are not suppose to be able to do so).

Comment: I fixed my mistake; do my corrections make it valid?

Comment: "assuming $h/24$ is a whole" is strange, you are suppose to prove it. don't forget the base case. Write $25^n25$ as either $25^n\cdot 25$ or $25^n25$.